# How to capture / check all URL's with double slashes (//) and correct them (JQuery?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment we've got a big problem (temporarily)!
In our shop we're using a 3rd party solution for promoting and searching for products.
We have around 3600 products which got harvested in the wrong way - the base-url had an extra forward slash ([www.sceneryworkshop.nl//](http://www.sceneryworkshop.nl//)) so now all products are called the wrong way and end-up in nomansland. We started a new data-sync, but it takes a lot of time to get in sync.

So I'm looking for a temporarily solution, even if it's dirty!
I don't have access to .htaccess or other server components. The shop runs on a closed-source platform (Lightspeed HQ) which is based on TWIG.

Anyone who knows how to change or redirect to the correct url? Javascript maybe?
The sources are located and called from a lot of places, so the only solution would be a global function that checks and corrects the url's.

I really hope someone has an answer for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have a solution assuming that jquery is loaded after the dom is rendered

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('a').each(function() {
    $split = $(this).attr('href').split('com//');
    $(this).attr('href', $split[0] + 'com/' + $split[1]);
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://www.google.com//search?q=Jquery" target="_blank">Jquery</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com//search?q=Java" target="_blank">Java</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com//search?q=J" target="_blank">J</a>
```

*Note:*
If you like to test the link in the snipped; hold ctrl and click on the link.

*Update*
Ok. i have read your comment and try some stuff in the inspector from your website. The following solution works!

```js
$('body a[href^="https://www.google.com//"]').each(function() {
    $x = $(this).attr('href').replace('com//', 'com/');
    $(this).attr('href', $x)
    console.log($x);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://www.google.com//search?q=Jquery" target="_blank">Jquery</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com//search?q=Java" target="_blank">Java</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com//search?q=J" target="_blank">J</a>
```

What i do here is simple, first i search every a element witch contains the following url: https://www.sceneryworkshop.nl//. then replace them with the correct url.

Comment: Thanks Henri! I tried with your code - replaced com// with nl// - but it doesn't work. Maybe it has to do with JQuery not loaded in the right order. How can I check if it renders after the DOM?